# Transfering login from mechanize to urllib or requests

Tags: python-requests, web-crawler, urllib3, mechanize-python

I'm currently trying to transfer some of my code to either urllib3 or requests. urllib3 would be the preferred method to reduce the modules imported.

This is the code currently working.

```
payload = ["<username>", "<password>"

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)
browser.select_form('form1')
browser['j_username'] = payload[0]
browser['j_password'] = payload[1]
browser.submit()
```

What I tried so far is

```
with requests.Session() as session:


  #not working
  payload = { "j_username" : "<username>", "j_password" : "<password>" }
  req = session.post(url, data = payload)
  print(req.url)

  #also not working
  req = session.get(url, auth=("<username>", "<password>") )
  print(req.url)
```

Also not working:

```
payload = {     "lang": "de",   "j_username": "<username>",     "j_password": "<password>",     "_eventId_proceed": "" }

req = session.post(url, data = payload)
```

I'm always getting the same url returned that so I can't login.

Is there a way to do this login in urllib / requests or do I have to stick with mechanize?
Also I would like to compare speed on those solutions.

Comment: Can you try posting the posting the form manually, and open the developer tools to find out what exactly is being posted to the URL for authorisation? There might be some other things (like `csrftokens`) that are posted along with username and password.

Comment: On Firefox dev-tools network analysis I got the info that the payload for the request looks like `lang=de&j_username=<USERNAME>&j_password=<PASSWORD>&_eventId_proceed=` 
The form looks like:
`{
 "lang": "de",
 "j_username": "<username>",
 "j_password": "<password>",
 "_eventId_proceed": ""
}`

Comment: So can you try sending `_eventId_proceeed` also?

Comment: I tried it with exactly that dict from my previous comment as payload, but it's still not working. So I'm still missing something or doing something wrong

Comment: Okay. Maybe print `req.text` to get some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, and maybe it will help someone else too.
I had to do a get request and use the url from that request because there is a redirect to the login-page and you can't open it directly (I would see a page like You may be seeing this page because you used the Back button while browsing a secure web site or application...)

```
#url1 = url that redirects to loginpage 
payload = { "lang": "de",   "j_username": "<username>",  "j_password": "<password>",     "_eventId_proceed": "" }
with requests.Session() as session:
    loginPage = session.get(url1)
    afterLogin = session.post(loginPage.url, data = payload)
    wantedPage = session.get(<url of wanted page>)
```